# How to get the current version number of a Trigger.io app

Tags: configuration, trigger.io

Is there a way to get the app config settings from inside my Trigger.io app without having to repeat the values in the [parameters](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/parameters.html) module? Specifically, I'm looking to grab the version number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success (today) with using **forge.config.version**

Example:

```
alert(forge.config.version)
```

This returned the value I had entered into the app's configuration.

Comment: I just tried this as well and it seems to work, although I couldn't find it documented anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It used to be available under `forge.config` in Javascript, but isn't anymore. For a while it wasn't available under this key (around v. 1.2). It has since reappeared.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know in what version that functionality was removed? I looked back through the release notes but didn't see it. Maybe before 1.2?

Comment: Don't know. It may never have been part of the public API.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `forge.config.version` still works